# Kendo Grid Computed Column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I update value of a non-editable column when some other column value changes. For example: **Total** column should be non-editable. User inline edits **Quantity** column and I want to update **Total** column. I want to do this client side. 
I have spent a lot of time on DataTables and still could not do it. So, moved to Kendo Grid. Hope it works this time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/egoroh/6) where computed column as **Total** is demonstrated. But I want the user to **view the numericupdown only when the cell is clicked**. This feature only appears when set to `editable : true` But then computed column won't work. How can I solve this problem? Some assistance required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is too late for you,

but anyway you can find you answer here:

http://jsfiddle.net/inikolova/H6tgv/9/

you should handle the `save` event of the kendo grid and then update the item using `model.set` function.